# "Bindable Method" with OneWayToSource mode

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to write a custom control that looks like a TextBox and that contains a method called Refresh() which main purpose will be to clear the Text and to roll back few other values.

The method shall become bindable somehow so that others can bind a property from their ViewModel with it. Hence why I am thinking that inside my custom control I will need an dependency property of type Action.

So far so logical but next problem is the method/dp may no get overriden on control side once users sets a two way binding on it. Basically I always have to deliver the method wrapper as Action to ViewModel and inside ViewModel other users may call it.

How do I do all this? It seems to me that I have to somehow get the binding of the method work like OneWayToSource.

I apologize in case its a duplicate. Futhermore thanks in advance guys.

**EDIT**: Please no alternative solutions. Those are the requirements and I have to stick to them.

Comment: I am not sure if you are taking the right direction. Let me ask this : what is the difference between YourControl.Refresh() and methods like Button.Focus()? Would you let a ViewModel trigger Button.Focus in some way? For me, a better way is to have a "Text" dependency property and let ViewModel bind to it. You can choose the binding mode depending how you want its value to be changed. Then in the Text's PropertyChangedCallback event handler, adjust your control's internal state based on the new value.

Comment: @KaiWang I may not use that apprach with Text property. I have to stick to the requirements. Having focus set from ViewModel is not so strange at all like you may think. The ViewModel accord to definition contains data but also logic of the view. The ViewModel may not know anything about the view but it may set buttons to is enabled or change focus to certain element or whatever usecase. Can somebody provide me with a solution to the requirements giving in the question. I really need this to make it work with a "bindable method" way.

Comment: Dude, in my humblest opinion, I think that you should take a deep breath and calm down. You *seem* to be getting *really* worked up with everyone who is trying to help you fix your issue... *some* of your comments here are bordering on rude. The problem is that (as far as I can see), there is no solution that fits your requirements. As developers, we are simply trying to find another way to achieve the same end result. I do accept that you said that those are the requirements, but *please* bear in mind that we are *trying* to help you. Please do not get offended by this comment.

Comment: No intetion to be rude here. English is not my first language sorry. Is just text without emotion so I dont know how you think i am rude hehe. But its not.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the simplest thing you can do here is to expose a `bool` property, maybe called `IsCleared`, and just call your method from that property when it becomes true. Exposing `ICommand` and/or `delegate` objects transfers the functionality out of your control, so you can't use those.

@ninjahedgehog, why can't you use a `bool` 'switch' property? Your requirement says 'so that others can bind a property from their ViewModel with it'... they can bind to a `bool` property from their view model. In my opinion, it *seems* to be your only option. As I said earlier, you can't use `ICommand` and/or `delegate` objects as that would transfer the functionality out of your control - that would enable other developers to write their own functionality rather than to just call yours.

What you really want is a method on your control that they could call from their view model... but view models shouldn't have any knowledge about the view controls, so you can't do that. The next best thing to that is creating a method that is called when a property is given a certain value. Here you have a few choices.

If you *really* don't like the `bool` switch idea, then how about an `enum` property? Create an `enum` with specific values like `ClearText` and whatever other functionality you would like to expose. Then the other developers simply set this property to the relevant instance to instantiate that functionality... I only suggested the `bool` switch property because it seems as if you only want to expose one piece of functionality.

One last point to note about using the `bool` switch property... as it is a switch, you need to reset it after use, or just never actually set it:

```
public bool IsTextClear
{
    get { if (value) ClearText(); }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your suggestion but like I already mentioned I know there are few alternatives to this but I may not use. I cannot use a boolean value. I have to use the method approach. So can you provide me a solution with method?

Comment: I cannot use any alternative. Thats just how things are. I accepted the fact that I have to get it working with method. I am asking you guys to accept my requirements and provide me a solution or workaround. ViewModel may not know about the controls or name of the controls in the view but ViewModel does as well contain logic for interfering with the View. The best example is enabling or disabling buttons from ViewModel. In my case it is not enabling or disabling a button from ViewModel its just an Action property called from ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you need this coz the person who is using your control can directly call the method from the code behind. But if you want that there should be some property like ClearMe on control and when set to true it should clear the control then you can define the dependency property and listen to its change in control like below and call Refresh from there.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClearMeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
             "ClearMe",
             typeof(bool),
             typeof(MyControl),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnClearMeChanged)
        );

        public bool ClearMe
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ClearMeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ClearMeProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnClearMeChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           var control = sender as MyControl;
           if((bool)e.NewValue)
           {
               control.Refresh()
           }
        }
```

and you can bind this property to your ViewModel property. whenever ViewModel property will change to true. Property Change will be fired in control and will refersh it.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the requirements I have given in the question. I am well aware that here are many aternatives but I have to stick to the requirements. Thanks for you idea and suggestion but also sorry I cannot use this approach with boolean value. Plus I would need to change in ViewModel always between true and false to fire the propertychanged event in view to execute refreshing. Thats not good. I have to use the method.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog: You could set the value to false in the view though once the clear has been done.

Comment: I cant. Thats not whats required. I have to make it work with " a bindable method" apprach. Please guys can anyone help me without all the alternatives suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I editted my answer, as I wasn't understanding what you wanted.  The only way I could come up with to do what you want was to use an Action DependencyProperty on the CustomControl and bind that to the ViewModel using a OneWayToSource binding, that way the Action from the control gets sent to the viewmodel.  Within your customcontrol, you can test to make sure that only OneWayToSource binding is used and do something if not.. in this case, I add some text and made the background red.

View

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Controls">      
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:TestViewModel x:Key="TestViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource TestViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
        <controls:CustomTextBox Width="300" Refresh="{Binding RefreshAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  />
        <Button Content="Refresh" Width="80" Command="{Binding RefreshFromView}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            RefreshFromView = new RelayCommand(ExecuteRefreshFromView);
        }

        public Action RefreshAction { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand RefreshFromView { get; set; }
        private void ExecuteRefreshFromView(object parameter)
        {
            if (RefreshAction != null)
                RefreshAction();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Control

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1.Controls
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            this.Loaded += CustomTextBox_Loaded;
        }

        void CustomTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindingExpression bindingExpression = GetBindingExpression(RefreshProperty);
            BindingMode mode = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Mode;

            if (mode != BindingMode.OneWayToSource)
            {
                Text = "Use OneWayToSource Binding only!";
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }

            Refresh = new Action(DoRefresh);
        }

        private void DoRefresh()
        {
            Text = null;
        }

        public Action Refresh
        {
            get { return (Action)GetValue(RefreshProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Refresh", typeof(Action), typeof(CustomTextBox));
    }
}
```

Comment: what?  just make an event then.

Comment: Create an event in the usercontrol that consumers can subscribe to.  You raise the event in the usercontrol and a method in the view gets called.

Comment: I dont know why you keep mentioning a usercontrol but i dont have any usercontrol. Read my question again please. You got me completely wrong. Read it again. I am looking to call a method inside viewmodel that was defined in view.

Comment: Editted my response to hopefully be more useful.

Comment: That is a nice approach but still not enough. You only considered the case when a control gets loaded but what if user changes DataContext? OneWayToSource binding is not always working the way the name describes it. I did a bunch of tests with one way to source binding and It seems to me that once DataContextChanged the Binding sets the target value to its default value (null). Which may not be the case because the Binding shall only update the source.

Comment: Within your custom control, capture datacontext changes and re-assign the Refresh action to a new value then.

Comment: But the bindable method may contain Path like this "Prop1.Prop2.Prop2.Prop4" so in such case I may not only listen to DataContextChanged. I would need to listen to nested objects too. Thats what makes it so complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying really.  Maybe you should try posting some code of what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Ah sorry I dont know how to explain but just listening to DataContextChanged event is not covering all use cases.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Command:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Do whatever you have to do
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

In your ViewModel:

```
public ICommand Command { get; set; }
```

In your XAML (assuming that your Custom Control is composed of a TextBox and a Button for example):

```
<Button Click="{Binding Command}" />
```

Comment: I think what OP wants is the other way round, execute a method on the view.

Comment: I want to execute a method which is declared in view at some point in my viewmodel. Commands is not what I am looking for because command invoke a method defined in viewmodel. The bindable method shall behave like OneWayToSource. Sorry Morgan M. I cant use your code.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your needs.